# What is wrong in the Bash script about parameters and Wget?

Tags: bash, wget

Runnning the command gives

```
wget_exam -h
Usage: wget_exam2 <fileType> <source>
exit     // then immediately Terminal shut dows
```

The code

```
# example wget_exam2 java http://www.example.com/ex_1
function wget_exam2 {
    while [[ $1 == -* ]]; do
    case "$1" in 
        -h|--help|-\? ) echo "Usage: wget_exam2 <fileType> <source>"; exit;;
            --) shift; break;;
        -*) echo "invalid option: $1"; echo "Usage: wget_exam2 <fileType> <source>"; exit;;
    esac
    done
    wget --random-wait -nd -r -p -A "$1" -e robots=off -U mozilla "$2"
}
```

Comment: Are you joking? You get the desired output from the -h switch...

Comment: do we have a `[smells-like-homework]` tag yet?

Comment: Simple question: what is actually wrong? What do you expect?

Comment: Questioner is expecting invocations of the function not to result in exits from their shell. Dennis' answer below explains why it does, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing this function from a shell prompt, the `exit` command is telling the shell to exit rather than the function. You should probably use `return` instead.

You can use a return value with `return` and test for that in the script that calls the function and use the `exit` *there* to exit the script (or not depending on the return value).

```
$ testfunc(){ return ${1:-0}; }
$ testfunc
$ echo $?
0
$ testfunc 0
$ echo $?
0
$ testfunc 1
$ echo $?
1
```